# How to test Service Contracts implemented as OSGi Bundles?

Tags: testing, osgi

We are in the process of transitioning towards SOA.

Our current goal is to try and ensure that more of the application is developed as "Services" (mainly to improve visibility of capability, re-use and de-risk change). Some of those services will be exposed as web services, but many (and probably the majority) will not, and be used for "internal" use only to help reap some of the benefits of SOA.

For those "internal" services we are currently intending on implementing them as OSGi bundles; however we are struggling to understand how best to test them. Our goal is to enable the current System Test team to test all types of services and we have been investigating tools like SoapUI and SOA Test; however it's becoming clearer that we may face some challenges in testing our services implemented as OSGi bundles using tools like these; and indeed asking the test team to do so.

So we're looking for some advice on how best to test aspects of our capability designed to act as a "service", but implemented as an OSGi bundle instead of a web service.

What tools would people recommend, and is this a type of testing that's traditionally done by a developer during unit test, or can it be done by a less technical tester, undertaking the same basic principles of testing interfaces (i.e. inputs, processing, outputs)?

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically use a Remote Service Admin implementation (like [Aries RSA](http://aries.apache.org/modules/rsa.html) or [Eclipse ECF](http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/)) to expose your internal services to the outside during testing to access them using an external system test tool.

I would not recommend to let an external team test your OSGi services though. It is much better to test the services in your own build using an integration testing tool like [pax exam](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM4/Pax+Exam). It allows to define which bundles and other config to install. Then it boots up an OSGi framework with your setup and runs modified junit tests against it. The advantage is that such tests are quite realistic and still quite simple.
See here for some pax exam tests in [aries rsa](https://github.com/apache/aries-rsa/blob/master/itests/felix/src/test/java/org/apache/aries/rsa/itests/felix/discovery/config/TestConfigDiscoveryRoundTrip.java) or [apache karaf](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/itests/src/test/java/org/apache/karaf/itests/HttpTest.java).
The first example uses the pax exam forked container for a very fast test (<1s per Test) while the second example uses the apache karaf container (~10s per Test) for tests that are very near a production system.

So you get much faster feedback than with an external system test team that will always lag a bit behind your current development. It also allows you to establish the policy that each team member runs the tests locally before committing.

Comment: I agree with Christian: testing bundles is a task for the developers who built the bundles. There are a number of testing tools, but they all involve putting bundles into a real OSGi framework and then prodding them. Christian mentions PAX Exam... bnd with Gradle also has a test runner for this purpose and can be used with the Bndtools IDE.